# DLL Error for one program and not another in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I am totally confused.  I am trying to make a connection to Oracle, and I use the *EXACT* same code for two different programs.  In the first one, it works flawlessly, in the second one I get an error.  They are used in the exact same way and I have double and triple checked the references in each program to ensure they are exactly the same.  The code is below as well as the text for the error.  This is created in VS2013 using a C# WPF environment.

```
 private void btnSendEmails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        string tableSpace = txtTableSpace.Text;
        string tableName = txtTableName.Text;
        string statement = "Select * FROM " + tableName;

        //create the connection to Oracle using the  above log in information
        string connectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" + tableSpace + ";User Id=" + userName + ";Password=" + password + ";";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cnn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter Dadpt = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(statement, cnn);


        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Dadpt.Fill(ds);

        cnn.Close();
        //OpenFileDialog attachment;

        CreateRTFMailItem(ds);
    }
```

I am just not sure why I would get a dll error for one and not the other...I feel like there is something more to this that I can't find.  The error says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Both programs are running on the same machine? In Debug mode I presume?

Comment: @Hank yes THey are

Comment: Do they both have the same Target Platform setting?

Comment: @hank  Yes they do. x86

Comment: Download [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and check there which DLL's are loaded, resp. where your program is searching.